# Access 2010 with query returning empty dataset

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with an embedded query that asks the user to enter a search string.  The problem is if the user enters something that is not in the database a null dataset is returned and the form 'does not open'.   In actual fact the form does open but since there is not data to display, they form is blank.

Question, is there any way to check to see if the form is blank?   This would allow me to prompt the user with something like "Search not found, please try again."  When they press OK, I can close the window.   Right now the user is left with a blank screen and very confused.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

Add the following event to not open the form. If you want to show the message, but not close the form, remove 'Cancel = True'. If you place the 'search' box in the header or footer, it will still appear even if no records.

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.RecordsetClone.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Records to display"
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```